# Social-auth AuthCanceled error after redirect from facebook

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

I've set up `social-auth-app-django` in production. But after facebook redirect I got `AuthCanceled` and still unable to get it work.

In my user model email address used to sign up. This is my user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    ...
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'social_django.context_processors.backends',
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
    ],
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'accounts.backends.ModelBackend'
)

LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '..'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '...'  # App Secret
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email',
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

Valid OAuth redirect URIs in facebook login app: `https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/`

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those landing on this question, after discussing the topic with OP via email, the problem was caused by an incorrect build of `redirect_uri` when exchanging the `code` for an `access_token`.

The incorrect build of this URI was caused because the Django backend sits behind Nginx, but the proper headers were not passed to it (`X-Forwarded-For` and `Host`), so Django was unaware of the right host it was services requests as, in the end, the URLs were pointing to `localhost` instead of the intended domain.

Comment: And setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False` (at least in my case).

Thank you so much Matias! I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

For me everything is working like a charm: Facebook, Google, Twitter and github.
This may be a configuration problem.

Here's how I've setup everything (note: I'm in *developer* mode in Facebook, but it works fine with my 2 accounts), I hope this can help:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    'compressor',
    'app',
)

MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/
# tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = 'xxx'

SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'xx'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'xxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'fields': 'name, email, age_range'
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Incredible. Still not works.. time to try another library.
Thank you for answer!

Comment: Here's the (long) solution I would try if I were you: try to make a new project and do a step by step inclusion of social-auth. I'm sure it will work. Then copy/paste all your files from the previous project to include them and verify it still works. I'm sure it will take longer to find another library. social-auth is a very good library, and I've had tons of problem (including loosing one of my clients!!) because of other bad social, not well maintained auth Python library (i prefer not to say which one).

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally, it works. After adding `X-Forwarded-For` and `host` header for nginx, and setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False` in settings.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know also what the difference between

```
https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/
```

and

```
https://example.com/social-auth/complete/facebook/
```

in my case i included both and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I searched many days to solve this problem. My solution is that the authentication need to SSL, so you should install ssl and use runsslserver instead of runserver. if you are already using https or after made, you need to add this commend - SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True in settings.py. In my case, I'm using https already, so I solved this problem just adding that code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33608442)